# Mystery wrapped in an enigma

Tags: gramática

I am trying to say, in Spanish:

> A mystery wrapped in an enigma

Would:

> Un misterio envuelto en un enigma

be correct grammar?

Answer (score 5):

It is the way I would translate it too. Sounds **perfectly correct** to me.

Would be OK too (to expand a little bit my answer):

> Un enigma que envuelve un misterio

or

> Un enigma que encierra un misterio

or even

> un enigma dentro de un misterio

(Although this is less close to your original sentence)

Actually in Spanish we say that mysteries and/or enigmas `envuelven` or `encierran` something.

> Un misterio (o enigma) envuelve la desaparición del avion en el triángulo de las Bermudas.
>
> Qué misterios encierra la *Casa Encantada de la Montaña Tenebrosa*?

Answer (score 2):

***Un misterio envuelto en enigma*** (without *un*) sounds more proficient, unless you need to mean a sole enigma, (only one in number).

Comment: Actually "envuelto en misterio" sounds good to be, but "Envuelto **en enigma**" no. I would be using "envuelto en **un** enigma" or "envuelto en enigmas" (plural), but all that might be just a personal preference.

Comment: Yes, thinking it better, you are right.